# Binding data to TextBox without showing text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When binding text/data to a TextBox, it is done like

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model=> model.Question)
```

but, when the PostBack happens, the text shows up in the TextBox. Is there a way to still bind the data to the textbox, but not display the text in the textbox?

I have a search functionality on my website, and when someone searches I want the results page to have the textbox without the text (the searched word).

Comment: Have you tried setting `Question` to null or empty string in the controller before displaying result view?

Comment: You can use `JavaScript` code to clear the input-text.

Comment: Show you controller code. If you use `return View(yourModel)` then of course it will show the text you entered. If your wanting to create a new model again, then redirect to the GET method.

Comment: AVD, if you post as answer I accept your answer.                         document.getElementById('search').value = '';

Comment: Just use <input name="question">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said Postback, so you're using Server side implementation, right?

If that's the case, the simplest way is to add a script that runs every page load.

For example, you have this search textbox:

```
<input type="textbox" id="search">
```

In your javascript :

```
<script type="text/javacript">
$(document).ready(function{
 //get the attribute of the search textbox and clear the text
  $('#search').val('');
});
</script>
```

If you're using Ajax implementation then just add a script when your form post succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Question property to null or empty on the controller action before displaying the result, or also you make it empty after the page is loaded in the document ready method using jquery.